# Url.Action not outputting custom mapped controller route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

This is for a .NET 5.0 MVC web application.

I have a controller to manage types of agencies in the Admin area of my site:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class AgencyTypesController : Controller
{        
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id)
    {
        ...
    }        
}
```

The current url is at `/Admin/AgencyTypes`, but I would like it to be `/Admin/Agencies/Types`, so I have this in my Startup:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "agencytypes",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/Agencies/Types/{action=Index}",
        defaults: new { controller = "AgencyTypes", action = "Index" }
    );
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

When I navigate to `/Admin/Agencies/Types`, it seems my routing has worked correctly, it hits the Index action in AgencyTypesController.

The problem is that my page has links to the Create and Edit methods, using `Url.Action`

```
@Url.Action("Create", "AgencyTypes", new { Area = "Admin" })
@Url.Action("Edit", "AgencyTypes", new { Area = "Admin", id = ID })
```

And rather than these urls being rendered as `/Admin/Agencies/Types/Create` and `/Admin/Agencies/Types/Edit/id`, it's still using the urls at `/Admin/AgencyTypes/Create` and `/Admin/AgencyTypes/Edit`

Is there something else I need to do to get `Url.Action` working with my custom route? Or is there something wrong with how I'm mapping my route?

Comment: There is [Url.RouteUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#generate-urls-by-route-1).

Comment: You should add more specific MapControllerRoute before general MapControllerRoute

Comment: @AliZeinali what do you mean, like I need one for each action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more specific route first:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "agencytypes",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/Agencies/Types/{action=Index}",
        defaults: new { controller = "AgencyTypes", action = "Index" }
    );
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

this is because when it gonna create a url it go through your routes which you defined and find the first one that match.

So when you add a general pattern like this `{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` first, it will be at the first of the list and so it always would be first pattern which match